# How to handle unicode data in cx_Oracle and python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I am using

```
Python 2.7
cx_Oracle 6.0.2
```

I am doing something like this in my code

```
import cx_Oracle
connection_string = "%s:%s/%s" % ("192.168.8.168", "1521", "xe")
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("system", "oracle", connection_string)
cur = connection.cursor()
print "Connection Version: {}".format(connection.version)
query = "select *from product_information"
cur.execute(query)
result = cur.fetchone()
print result
```

I got the output like this

> Connection Version: 11.2.0.2.0
>
> (1, u'????????????', 'test')

I am using following query to create table in oracle database

```
CREATE TABLE product_information 
    ( product_id          NUMBER(6) 
    , product_name        NVARCHAR2(100) 
    , product_description VARCHAR2(1000));
```

I used the following query to insert data

```
insert into product_information values(2, 'दुःख', 'teting');
```

**Edit 1**

Query: `SELECT * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY', 'NLS_CHARACTERSET');`

Result

> NLS_LANGUAGE: AMERICAN, NLS_TERRITORY: AMERICA, NLS_CHARACTERSET:
> AL32UTF8

Comment: Check your NLS_Characterset to see if it is UTF8. SELECT *   
from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS   
WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY', 'NLS_CHARACTERSET');

Comment: It returns something like this `NLS_LANGUAGE:
AMERICAN,

NLS_TERRITORY:
AMERICA,
NLS_CHARACTERSET:
AL32UTF8`

Comment: Is there a way to check whether your client tool where you are displaying these characters have the required font set to display these unicode characters?

Comment: I think it supports the original characters. When I do something like this `print "दुःख"` ->Output:  `दुःख`

Comment: Please check this link. A few solutions are discussed here. https://community.oracle.com/thread/3996112

Comment: @ArtBajji thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10):

I solved the problem.

First I added `NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` as the environment variable in the system where Oracle is installed 
Second I passed the encoding and nencoding parameter in connect function of cx_Oracle like below.

```
cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, connection_string,
                                            encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
```

This issue is also discussed here at https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/157

Comment: Erroor: 'nencoding' sent to create_engine(), using configuration OracleDialect_cx_oracle/QueuePool/Engine.

Comment: The environment variable option will no longer work for character sets from cx_oracle version 8 onwards. The default is now UTF-8, so the explicit parameters should also no longer be needed.