# Why one AL32UTF8 character not display the I-Acute, yet other one displays the tilde-N?

Tags: oracle11g, character-encoding

My Oracle 11g is configured with AL32UTF8

`NLS_CHARACTERSET   AL32UTF8`

Why does the tilde-N display as tilde-N in the second record, but the Acute-I and K 
not display with Acute-I and K in the first record?

[image: multibyte]

**Additional Information:**
The hex code for the Accent-I is **CD**[image]
When I take the HEX code from the dump and convert it using `UNISTR()`, the character displays with the accent.

```
     select 
     unistr('\0052\0045\0059\004B\004A\0041\0056\00CD\004B') 
     as hex_to_unicode
  from dual;
```

Comment: Does your client tool have the font set to display Acute-I and K? See if there is a way to check that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174710/how-to-handle-unicode-data-in-cx-oracle-and-python-2-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an issue with whatever client you are using to display the results than your database. What are you using?

You can check if the database results are correct using the `DUMP` function. If the value in your table has the correct byte sequence for your database character set, you're good.

**Edit:**

OK, I'm pretty sure your data is bad. You're talking about
[LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00cd/index.htm), which is Unicode *code point* U+00CD. That is not the same as byte 0xCD. You're using database character set AL32UTF8, which uses UTF-8 encoding. The correct UTF-8 encoding for the U+00CD character is the two-byte sequence 0xC38D.

What you have is UTF-8 byte sequence 0xCD4B, which I'm pretty sure is invalid.

The Oracle `UNISTR` function takes the code point in UCS-2 encoding, which is roughly the same as UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Demonstration here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e9d1f/1

Comment: eaolson: Thanks for responding.The client, TOAD, renders the character when I ran the hex characters through UNISTR.